# Anonymous sign in with Firebase affecting Facebook login

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, fbsdkloginkit

I'm having some issues with trying to log/authorize facebook in conjunction with Firebase anonymous sign in.

I currently have a regular `UIButton` that attempts to log the user in with the below code.

```
let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], from: self, handler: { (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error) -> Void in
        // get fbsdk token and login through firebase
    })
```

Typically, clicking on the button will bring up the normal behavior where an `alertController` displays and asks the user if they want to use facebook.com to sign in.  After clicking continue, Safari (or facebook) opens to authorize the app.

This is all fine and dandy, but if the user first anonymously signs in from Firebase, clicking onto the same button to login through facebook will now fail.  After the alertController pops up to ask the user, instead of presenting Safari for facebook authorization, it looks as if the screen (Safari) aborts midway during presentation and just stays on the current screen.  If you click on the button again, the app will finally crash without any error messages

> (it will just show a EXC_BAD_ACCESS message on the AppDelegate).

As an example, I've put the code below to show how to guarantee facebook login failure.

```
Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { (user, error) in
    if let error = error {
         print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    if let user = user {
         let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
         loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], from: self, handler: { (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error) -> Void in
               // get fbsdk token and login through firebase
         })
    }
}
```

Obviously in my actual code, I'm not trying to log in immediately after I sign in anonymously but it demonstrates that the anonymous signing clearly affects `FBSDKLoginManager` somehow.  I've looked on SO but haven't really seen any question regarding this.  Wondering if this is a bug or if I'm just missing something.

This is on iOS / Swift FYI.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager() loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], from: self, handler: { (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error) -> Void in // get fbsdk token and login through firebase }) Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { (user, error) in if let error = error { print(error.localizedDescription) } if let user = user { let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager() loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], from: self, handler: { (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error) -> Void in // get fbsdk token and login through firebase }) } }

Comment: Please add a quick explanation of how your answer solves this question. Also, reformat your code using the recommended markdown found at the top of the editor. Thanks.